# How to fix OWASP Insecure Temporary File issue reported in an application secured using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using IBM AppScan to find potential vulnerabilities in an application that uses Spring Security. AppScan has reported an Insecure Temporary File Download issue for the application.

The tool reports that requests for URLs like `contact-us.1`, `contact-us.~1`, `contact-us.bak`, etc. are responded with the HTTP status code 200 and the same content. The application in question does have a Contact Us page mapped to the URL `contact-us`. Controller code for the page is shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = UrlContraints.URL_CONTACT_US, method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String contactUs(HttpServletRequest request
                        , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { 
    return "pages/home/contact-us"; 
}
```

**Efforts**

I have put this code segment in Spring Security configuration, but it is not working.

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("*.ARC", "*.arc", "*.BAC", "*.bac"
                                 , "*.BACKUP", "*.backup"
                                 , "*.bak", "*.BAK"
                                 , "*.inc", "*.include"
                                 , "*.save", "*.sav", "*.tar.lzma", "*.tmp"
                                 , "*.temp", "*.TMP"
                                 , "*.wim", "*.1", "*.a"
                                 , "*.lst", "*.lzma", "*.old", "*.-old"
                                 , "*.OLD", "*.-OLD", "*.old2"
                                 , "*.orig", "*.ORIG", "*.htm", "*.html"
                                 "*.txt"
                                 , "*.$*", "*.~*", "*.0", "*.ar")
                    .denyAll()
```

But this is also not working.

Please help me how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Both are same. I want to fix Insecure Temporary File. I do not have any link, instead tool try to fire something like these urls contact-us.1, contact-us.~1, contact-us.bak etc. and got 200 OK response from application. I want to fix this issue.

Comment: Actually it is returning the same page just like contact-us page if the url is contact-us.~1 etc for contact-us prefix. for url matching not exist then it will return 404 page.

Comment: Yes. I have and it working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC performs `.*` suffix pattern matching by default so that a controller method mapped to `contact-us` is also implicitly mapped to `contact-us.*`. This has been called out clearly in the [Spring MVC documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match) (relevant portion copied below).

> By default Spring MVC performs ".*" suffix pattern matching so that a
>   controller mapped to `/person` is also implicitly mapped to `/person.*`.
>   The file extension is then used to interpret the requested content type
>   to use for the response (i.e. instead of the "Accept" header), e.g.
>   `/person.pdf`, `/person.xml`, etc.

If this is undesirable, the solution has also been provided in the documentation itself:

> To completely disable the use of file extensions, you must set both of these:
>
> `useSuffixPatternMatching(false)`, see `PathMatchConfigurer`
>
> `favorPathExtension(false)`, see `ContentNeogiationConfigurer`

## Java config

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        ...
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```

## XML config

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    ...
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```